# Getting runtime error on refreshing listobject named range

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Below is my code to send mail:

```
Sub SendRequestForApprovalMail()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.StatusBar = "Step 1/2 - Retrieving your pending approvals from SharePoint..."
  Range("T_myPendingApprovals[#All]").ListObject.Refresh

 'new in v.5.0 - date format is changed as for some users the date format looks strange
   Union(Range("T_myPendingApprovals[Start]"), Range("T_myPendingApprovals[End]")).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
   Union(Range("T_myPendingApprovals[Modified]"), Range("T_myPendingApprovals[Created]")).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"

 If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("T_myPendingApprovals[Person]")) = 0 Then
  Application.StatusBar = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MsgBox "No entries with pending approval existing for you." & vbLf & vbLf & "Your supervisor should enter his name in the column 'Approved by', not you. Only then the records will be displayed in the mail for approval.", vbExclamation, "Approval mail generation"
  End
 End If

 Application.StatusBar = "Step 2/2 - Preparing approval mail..."

 SendMail "Request for vacation approval for " & UserNameWindows, _
           "Hi ..., <br><br>" & _
          "Please approve my vacation as stated below. To evaluate potential capacity issues in the team as well as " & _
          "towards important milestones, please refresh your offine copy of the " & _
          "<a href=""" & Range("DownloadPage") & """>Team availability Tracker</a> and consider all other parallel vacations in the chart for your approval decision.<br><br>" & _
          "Please enter your name in the column approver on the " & _
          "<a href=""" & Range("ApprovalView") & """>SharePoint</a>. " & _
          "Please do not just reply on this mail, make use of the SharePoint for 100% traceability and do the update(s) there. Only if the name of the supervisor appears in the column '[last] modified by', the approval can be considered as valid. Use the voting button to indicate that the approval took place.<br><br>Best regards,<br>" & FirstName _
           , , , , Export_Range_asImage(Range("T_myPendingApprovals[#All]"))
End Sub
```

I am getting a runtime error(application defined or object defined error) in the bottom line of the code.

```
 Range("T_myPendingApprovals[#All]").ListObject.Refresh
```

T_myPendingApprovals[#All]" is named range in the sheet "my pending approvals"

Comment: Why not just refresh the listobject by it's full name?

Comment: can you give an example?? @QHarr

Answer (score 0):

[`ListObject.Refresh`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-refresh-method-excel) expects a variable that represents a ListObject object. You will need to use the full name of the object as seen in Name Box.

For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetListObjectNames()

    Dim currObject As ListObject

    For Each currObject In ActiveSheet.ListObjects

        Debug.Print currObject.Name

    Next currObject

End Sub
```

If "Table1" was returned as the name

```
Dim myTable As ListObject
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1") 'use actual sheet name. Don't assume Activesheet
myTable.Refresh
```

In your example should be something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("my pending approvals").ListObjects("T_myPendingApprovals").Refresh
```

Failing that kick of expensive refresh events such as:

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Comment: sorry but still throwing the same error on refreshing .. @QHarr

Comment: what is the name of your table that you are refreshing? And is the error on this line specifically?  Range("T_myPendingApprovals[#All]").ListObject.Refresh

Comment: the table name will be `T_myPendingApprovals`

Comment: So  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("T_myPendingApprovals").Refresh

Comment: @CallumDA Doh.... yes...sorry...jumping between screens... today has not been a good day.

Comment: Or use the actual sheet name is far safer than assuming it is in Activesheet

Comment: tried it with actual sheet name still throwing the same error @QHarr

Comment: is there any other way to refresh ?? @QHarr

Comment: yes         i am using excel only                                       @QHarr

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("my pending approvals").Calculate  ?

Comment: No what I mean is if you try ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("my pending approvals").Calculate that  is a code line to calculate that sheet.